# Как настроить вывод списка declaration для phpstorm(idea)

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm

Всем привет. Проблема вот в чем: 
При нажатии на <kbd>Crtl</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> у меня сразу выскакивает окошко с нужным мне классом, но вдобавок он мне еще предлагает тот же класс, только уже с расширением php.

Как можно это пофиксить?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В каких случаях это происходит? Есть возможность подготовить локальный пример или дать ссылку на открытый проект, где это воспроизводится?

Comment: как появится возможность выложу, на данный момент проект на ноуте, который без адаптера не робит